After Running a PowerShell Script to Update Credentials for a Specific Data Source any Windows Password Saved is Broken
I have a powershell script that loops through all reports and updates the windows credentials to use a service account but only for specific data sources.
After I run the script any report that has a windows auth account has had the password change (but not the username) even for data sources it shouldn't touch.
When I open a report that uses a data source not listed (ie datasource3) the windows username will be the same as it was before but the password will have been changed which causes the report to fail.
I do not want to touch any credentials that are not datasource1 or datasource2
I have tired using IF statements, using SWITCH statements and even adding the windows username to exclude and while the script tells me the report was excluded it still breaks the password.
        --#Variables
        --$ReportPortalUri = 'http://blah.co.nz/reports';
        --$reportFolder = "ReptFolder";

        --#Create new web session to your Power BI Report portal
        --$session = New-RsRestSession -ReportPortalUri $ReportPortalUri;

        --#Get list of all reports
        --$reports = Get-RsCatalogItems -ReportServerUri $ReportPortalUri -RsFolder "/$($reportFolder)" -Recurse | Where {$_.TypeName -eq 'PowerBIReport'};

        --#Loop through selected reports
        --ForEach ($report in $reports)
        --{
        --  $report.Path
        --  try
        --  {
        --      #Get data source object
        --      $dataSources = Get-RsRestItemDataSource -WebSession $session -RsItem $report.Path

        --      #Update data source object
        --      foreach ($dataSource in $dataSources)
        --      {
        --          switch -Regex ($dataSource.ConnectionString) {
        --              'datasource1' {
        --                  $dataSource.DataModelDataSource.AuthType = 'Windows'
        --                  $dataSource.CredentialRetrieval = 'Store'
        --                  $dataSource.DataModelDataSource.Username = 'win_srv_account1'
        --                  $dataSource.DataModelDataSource.Secret = '1234'
        --              }
        --              'datasource2' {
        --                  $dataSource.DataModelDataSource.AuthType = 'UsernamePassword'
        --                  $dataSource.CredentialRetrieval = 'Store'
        --                  $dataSource.DataModelDataSource.Username = 'sql_srv_account2'
        --                  $dataSource.DataModelDataSource.Secret = '1234'
        --              }
        --              default {
        --                  Write-Host "No matching condition for connection string $($dataSource.ConnectionString). Skipping."
        --                  continue
        --              }
        --          }
        --      }     

        --      #Update data source object on server
        --      Set-RsRestItemDataSource -WebSession $session -RsItem $report.Path -RsItemType 'PowerBIReport' -DataSources $dataSources
        --  }
        --  catch 
        --  {
        --      $Error[0].Exception
        --  }
        -


Is this exactly how your code appears in the original, or have you edited it for this post? I ask because the continue inside your default branch applies to the switch (when the test expression is a collection), not the foreach - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_continue?view=powershell-7.4#using-continue-in-a-switch-statement - as a result it's a null-op in your code sample, but it might be the cause of your issue if the original is different...

Seems like you need a new Boolean variable (declared above the foreach) which you set the value from inside your switch blocks, then conditionally execute Set-RsRestItemDataSource based on that new condition. You may also need include break at the end of each switch block to stop the switch statement processing further matching statements. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch for details on break/continue in the context of a swtich

The script currently works for any report that matches the regex, the issue seems to be anytime the script it run any report that falls outside of this has the password altered (but not the username)
Do you know if there is anything about calling the session that might cause this.
If I publish a report with no credentials it adds the creds for the data sources that match and does nothing for the data sources that do not match.
However once there are credentials in the un-matched sources when the script runs their password stops being correct.

I found the issue.
I added breaks to the case statement and moved the update to after each case.
One issue is the below line updates all sources, not just the source you want.
-DataSources $dataSources
Should be
-DataSource $dataSources
